ArrayFormula to give Different Serial Numbering for Different Names
Google Sheet Link
I want to have an Arrayformula at A1 to produce this output:

I want to have a different serial numbering for different names. There can be any number of names, names would not be sorted & could repeat any number of time.


You may try:
=vstack("Header",
        map(B2:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,countif(B2:Σ,Σ)))))


Alternate formula:
=arrayformula(if(len(B2:B),countifs(B2:B,B2:B,row(B2:B),"<="&row(B2:B)),))


Damn, this works great! Do you have any material where I can understand this formula and use of Σ ? Also I had been trying to use Arrayforula, Countifs. Row, Unique formulas to achieve it since like 3hrs, is it possible to get a formula using these? if yes could you please give one?

Updated the answer with alternative. its been a year or more vstack is here. Youtube has many explanatory videos on map\lambda usage which you can check out.

Thank you so much! Could you please explain the use of Σ or give any material for this?

And also if suppose my  instead of just column B, I want to consider the concatenation of column B & C, so I changed your formula to =vstack("Header",
map(B2:B&C2:C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,countif(B2&C2:Σ,Σ))))) but this given an error saying "The default output of this reference is a single cell in the same row but a matching value could not be found. To get the values for the entire range use the ARRAYFORMULA function." whereas changing the same for Alternate formula works completely fine.

map(B2:B,C2:C,lambda(name,code,if(name="",,countif(index(B2:name&C2:code),name&code))))

Which formula would be more faster ?

cant say for sure. however you can test for yourself using one of the methods described in this question here OR try your luck with the Benchmark sheet attached in the comment here

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78759533/arrayformula-to-get-a-specific-serial-numbering
