Arrayformula to get a specific serial numbering
Google Sheet Link




NAME
QUALITY
CATEGORY
SR.NO.




Monu
gffg
B
1


David
rtet
G
1


John
dsadas
Q
1


John
iop
Q
1


John
bvn
A
2


John
Bp




Monu
hhsd
Y
2


Monu
dfghfh
R
3


Monu
hgfh




David
ljk
F
2


David
rty
G
1


David
wsddBPmer
V



Monu
jhgn
Y
2


David
ghf
A
3


John
dfghfh
Q
1


John
fgdfg
C
3


John
fdbv




John
gdf
A
2


Kelly
dgf
X
1



I want an ArrayFormula at D1 which exactly gives the same result as shown.
Criterias:

Each unique name has a different serial number.
Each unique name with same category has same serial number, with different category would have different serial number.
Name with CATEGORY blank would not have serial number.
Name with QUALITY containing "bp" (anycase) would not have serial number.



You may try:
=map(A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(Σ,let(Λ,offset(Σ,,2),if(or(ifna(xmatch("*bp*",offset(Σ,,1),2)),Λ=""),,
 let(z,filter(C:C,A:A=Σ,C:C<>"",not(regexmatch(B:B&"","(?i)bp"))),y,unique(z),x,{y,sequence(rows(y))},vlookup(Λ,x,2,))))))



This works great! but I am facing 2 problems: (1) My columns are not adjacent in my actual dataset, and it can be moved anywhere anytime (This formula is only for adjacent columns). (2) Can you please convert the formula to only open references like even if I convert the formula to ={"SR. NO." ; map(A2...} and put it in G1 and drag row 2 to any other row the 2 in A2 changes to that row number. Can you please help me with these two problems?

OP asked me to put forward an answer based on a previous question. Here is my suggestion, but it probably won't address the issues referred to in @Aashit's comment to @rockinfreakshow which I have only just read.
=ArrayFormula(let(bp,regexmatch(B2:B,"(?i)bp"),ifs(C2:C="","",bp,"",true,byrow(A2:C,
lambda(r,let(uniq,UNIQUE(filter({A2:A,C2:C},C2:C<>"",not(bp),A2:A=index(r,1))),
xmatch(1,(index(uniq,0,1)=index(r,1))*(index(uniq,0,2)=index(r,3)))))))))


You could select individual columns maybe like this:
=ArrayFormula(let(bp,regexmatch(B2:B,"(?i)bp"),ifs(C2:C="","",bp,"",true,byrow({A2:A,C2:C},
lambda(r,let(uniq,UNIQUE(filter({A2:A,C2:C},C2:C<>"",not(bp),A2:A=index(r,1))),
xmatch(1,(index(uniq,0,1)=index(r,1))*(index(uniq,0,2)=index(r,2)))))))))


Not sure about the second point. You could include a header like this:
=ArrayFormula({"SR No";let(bp,regexmatch(B2:B,"(?i)bp"),ifs(C2:C="","",bp,"",true,byrow({A2:A,C2:C},
lambda(r,let(uniq,UNIQUE(filter({A2:A,C2:C},C2:C<>"",not(bp),A2:A=index(r,1))),
xmatch(1,(index(uniq,0,1)=index(r,1))*(index(uniq,0,2)=index(r,2))))))))})

and it is true that if you inserted cells above the data in cols A-D then A2 in the formula would change to A3 etc.?
Try this version as suggested in the comment:
=ArrayFormula({"SR No";let(rcount,counta(tocol($A:$A,1)),name,index($A:$A,2):index($A:$A,rcount),
qual,index($B:$B,2):index($B:$B,rcount),cat,index($C:$C,2):index($C:$C,rcount),bp,regexmatch(qual,"(?i)bp"),
ifs(cat="","",bp,"",true,byrow({name,cat},
lambda(r,let(uniq,UNIQUE(filter({name,cat},cat<>"",not(bp),name=index(r,1))),
xmatch(1,(index(uniq,0,1)=index(r,1))*(index(uniq,0,2)=index(r,2))))))))})


Thank you so much, this solves the 1st problem as mentioned above, can you please overcome the 2nd problem too?

I had already tried this, but as you said thag A2 will change to A3, I don't want it to change to A3 in any case, there's no way I can stop it?

Well suppose it works OK in G1 but you want to put the formula in H2. You can anchor the ranges like $A$2:$A or even use indirect("A2:A") but the problem is that the formula generates 1000 rows (if that is the size of the sheet) and they won't fit. You would then need to count the actual numbers of rows in the data. If there are no spaces between the data in column A, you could use =counta(tocol(A:A,1)) and then index up to this point in each array that you're using.

Thank you for this but sir I would probably have random empty rows/spaces in between, I want the formula working at Row 1 only. It would really mean a lot!
